# Posting JSON to REST Service

Tags: c#, .net, rest

I am attempting to consume a Data source from Plex a cloud ERP System with Rest. I am receiving a forbidden status code upon sending the PUT

[image: HTTP Header]

[image]

```
public  static string Put(string url,string Body,PCNModel pcn)
    {
        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

        int timeOutSec = 90;
        string accept = "application/json";
        string acceptEncoding = "gzip, deflate";
        string contentType = "application/json";
        var credentials = pcn.UserName + ":" + pcn.Password;
        var bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(credentials);
        var encodedCredentials = Convert.ToBase64String(bytes);
        var authorizationHeaderValue = encodedCredentials;
        HttpResponseMessage response = new HttpResponseMessage();


        client.Timeout = new TimeSpan(0, 0, timeOutSec);
        //client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Accept", string.Format(accept));
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Accept", (accept));

        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Accept-Encoding", string.Format(acceptEncoding));
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue(contentType));
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", string.Format("Basic {0}", authorizationHeaderValue));
        HttpContent httpBody = Body;
        httpBody.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue(contentType);
        response = client.PutAsync(url, httpBody).Result;
        var error = response.StatusCode.ToString();
        var requestMessage = response.RequestMessage;
        var responseContent = response.Content;
        var responseReasonPhrase = response.ReasonPhrase;
        var responseHeader = response.Headers;     


        MessageBox.Show(error);
        MessageBox.Show(requestMessage.ToString());
        //MessageBox.Show(responseContent.ToString());
        //MessageBox.Show(responseReasonPhrase.ToString());
        //MessageBox.Show(responseHeader.ToString());

         var content = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
        return content;
    }
```

I am not sure where it is bouncing back at me.

Comment: This `HttpContent httpBody = Body;` looks odd. since in `string Put(string url,string Body,PCNModel pcn)`, that parameter is a `string`

Comment: I tested your code on my api and the authorization seems work correctly. What is the exact error message? Maybe that put verb is not allowed (or not enabled)? Can you try this call with curl or powershell?

Comment: @bdn02 I get the result of: Status Code 403, ReasonPhrase: Forbidden, Version 1.1, Content: System.Net.Http.StreamContent, Headers: 
{
pragma: no cache
cache-Control: no cache
Date: Wed, 06 Mar 2019 02:04:28 GMT
Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.5
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
X-Powered-By: ASP.Net
Content-Length:0
Expires: -1
}
I get the same result in powershell also.

Comment: @Nkosi I've updated it to this: 
response = client.PostAsJsonAsync(url, Body).Result;

I get the same result as above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that the credentials I was provided were incorrect. Which prevented me from processing web services calls to the endpoint.

Answer (score 0):

You need to parse body to json before calling PutAsync here is a small code sinppet

```
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("authKey", authKey);
var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(product, Formatting.None, new JsonSerializerSettings { NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore });
var content = new StringContent(json, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
var response = await client.PutAsync(url, content);
if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
{

}
else
{
    var result = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
    throw new Exception("Error Occured in Update Product" + result);
}
```